# RubyMine Rails 5 Savon net_http Errno::ECONNRESET SSL_Connect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, rubymine, savon

I think I have read all topics related to this subject, but still no solution.
I am using:

- RubyMine 2017.2.4
- Ruby 2.4.1
- Rails 5.1.0
- Savon

When I connect in my rails console with Savon to a server, I get the following error:

Errno::ECONNRESET: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the
remote host. - SSL_connect

This is the code I use:

```
wsdlUrl = 'https://some.server.com/ws/schema/Echo.wsdl'
licenseKey = '1234567890'

client = Savon.client(wsdl: wsdlUrl,
                  log:true,
                  ssl_verify_mode: :none)

response = client.call(:echo, 
                        message: { licenseKey: licenseKey,
                                   value: 'Hello World'})

puts "\nResult \"#{response.body[:echo_response][:value]}\" was returned"
```

I have tried to following:

- Download the ca-bundle.crt and added to my system environment (and restart
  everything)
- Updated my gems
- Reinstall Ruby, Rails and RubyMine
- Created a new app and copied code
- added "require openssl" to the code
- added the following code:

  ```
  require 'open-uri'
  require 'net/https'
  module Net
    class HTTP
      alias_method :original_use_ssl=, :use_ssl=
      def use_ssl=(flag)
         path = ( Rails.env == "development") ? "lib/ca-bundle.crt" : "/usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"
         self.ca_file = Rails.root.join(path).to_s
         self.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
         self.original_use_ssl = flag
       end
     end
   end
  ```

Just nothing is working anymore.

The strange this is this:

When I run the rails (development) console, and I enter the code above I get the ssl_connect error. When I change some code in RubyMine, and DON'T restart the console, I won't get any errors. When I rerun the Rails Console, I get the ssl-connect error again.

Does anyone know where I can look

EDIT 1:
I found out that if I put above code in a document (echo.rb) it will work when I call the document in the terminal as: ruby echo.rb

Comment: does it work from a script?

Comment: It does work when I call the script from the terminal. I placed the code in a document echo.rb. When I run ruby echo.rb it will work...

Comment: sorry, can't help with Rails.

Comment: `openssl s_client -connect some.server.com:443 -servername so.server.com` return *`gethostbyname failure`*. Perhaps you should provide accurate information if you want help. Or, ask one of your team members if you can't provide the information.

Comment: Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Answer (score 0):

For all that are having the same problem:

first

```
 $ gem install 'http' (or add gem 'http' to your Gemfile and install)
```

then add this in your code:

```
 require 'http'
```